# Conversation view issue in Office 365 Outlook in imported PST file

Tags: office365, outlook-redemption

we created Outlook PST file using Redemption dll. Then import PST file in local outlook 2007 application where Conversation  view is working fine. means email messages are displaying in grouping on subject. but if we import same PST file in Office 365 online Outlook then conversation view does not work for some of email messages.

Comment: Did you make sure PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX property is correctly set?

Comment: Dmitry, that field we set correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the good and bad messages using OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI? What are the differences?

Comment: Dmitry, i checked using outlook spy and value of PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX is set with binary value. Should it be same for all same subjects email messages?

Comment: The first 22 bytes should be the same - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: We checked using outlook spy that value of PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX have first 22 bytes are same for all emails in account., is it correct?

Comment: That is correct. So what is the difference between the good and the bad messages?

Comment: I don't know what is difference